# Flexbox not gaining height until wrapped

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have a weird behaviour with a flexbox. I am trying to make something that looks exactly like what it shows in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud7qpwwb/1/).

Which work perfectly, however when I run the same code on my own server it does this:

[image: the background is not expanding...]

As you can see the background colour indicates the containing div is only the size of the padding. I have tried everything I can think of to make it expand to fit the content but it doesnt work.

A clue is that when I squish the page, the wrapping puts the right hand box on top of the left one and they both look good:

[image: This is what I want]

Which is exactly what I want.

A html sample:

```
<div id="objectives_frontpage">

<div id="objectives_infopanel">
    <div id="objectives_title">The topic name</div>
    <div id="objectives_description">A description of the stuff...</div>
</div>

<div id="objectives_frontpage_info">

        <div id="objectives_objectivepanel">
        <div class="objectives_objective objectives_level_1">
            <div class="objectives_objective_title">Recall common examples of fluids and non-fluids.</div>
            <div class="objectives_objective_level">Level 1</div>
            <div class="objectives_objective_description">Give a few examples of fluids and a few examples of non-fluids.</div>
            <div class="objectives_objective_assessbar">
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess objectives_objective_1">1</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess objectives_objective_2">2</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess">3</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess">4</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="objectives_objective objectives_level_2">
            <div class="objectives_objective_title">Recall common examples of fluids and non-fluids.</div>
            <div class="objectives_objective_level">Level 1</div>
            <div class="objectives_objective_description">Give a few examples of fluids and a few examples of non-fluids.</div>
            <div class="objectives_objective_assessbar">
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess objectives_objective_1">1</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess objectives_objective_2">2</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess objectives_objective_3">3</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess">4</div>
                <div class="objectives_objective_selfassess">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="objectives_leaderboard">
            Nothing here yet...
        </div>
</div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#objectives_frontpage { margin: 20px 5px 20px 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap; }  
#objectives_infopanel { height: auto; } 
#objectives_title { font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-shadow: 3px 3px black; margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; }  
#objectives_description { padding: 5px; color: black; text-shadow: 1px 1px white; } 
#objectives_frontpage_info { flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; }
   #objectives_objectivepanel { display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; flex: 1; } 
   #objectives_leaderboard { flex: 1; } 

.objectives_objective { flex: 1; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
.objectives_level_1 { background: #00CC33; }
.objectives_level_2 { background: #009900; }
.objectives_level_3 { background: #CCCC00; }
.objectives_level_4 { background: #999900; }
.objectives_level_5 { background: #CC6600; }
.objectives_level_6 { background: #FF3333; }
.objectives_level_7 { background: #990000; }

.objectives_objective_title { display: flex; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-shadow: 3px 3px black; padding: 5px; }
.objectives_objective_level { display: flex; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); color: white; text-shadow: 1px 1px black; }
.objectives_objective_description { display: flex; font-size: 12px; color: white; text-shadow: 1px 1px black; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.objectives_objective_assessbar { display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; padding: 5px; }
.objectives_objective_selfassess { display: flex; flex: 1; justify-content: center; align-items: center; font-size: 20px; height: 50px; color: white; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px; }
.objectives_objective_selfassess:hover { cursor: pointer; color: black; }

.objectives_objective_1 { background: #00CC33; }
.objectives_objective_2 { background: #999900; }
.objectives_objective_3 { background: #CC6600; }
.objectives_objective_4 { background: #FF3333; }
.objectives_objective_5 { background: #990000; }
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Oh, and I have checked there are no conflicts with the rest of the sites CSS, as this section should be independent of the rest of the sites code.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or a snippet with your code because both the fiddle and the sample code seem to work fine

Comment: Ill try and do a more thorough one, but its hard because outside of this its basically the whole site! Its partly why im confused, nothing outside of this should be impacting it... give me a little while and ill try and fiddle the site :)

Answer (score 0):

So there was a faux-par with the container of this, which was stretching over the page, and then this ended up being placed below it meaning it couldn't expand into the space.

I took this code and put it inside that container, then set each objective to flex: 1; and it worked.

Thanks karolas for asking for more info, I found this whilst in the process of making the biggest fiddle I ever did - need more duck debugging.